# Identify and strip characters from colums

Tags: r, character, symbols, gsub

I have a large dataset in which I want identify and remove characters and signs to keep only the number value.

For example I want `-£1125.91m` to be `-1125.91`

```
dataset
  Event                       var1       var2  
  <fct>                       <chr>      <chr> 
1 Labour Costs YoY            13.34m     0.026 
2 Unemployment Change (000's) $16.91b    -0.449
3 Unemployment Rate           -£1125.91m 0.89k 
4 Jobseekers Net Change       ¥1012.74b  9.56m
```

At the moment I know how to remove a single character from the column. Like this:

```
dataset$`var1` <- gsub("k", "", dataset$`var`)
```

Doing this manually will be a lot of work because the dataset is really big. I was wondering if you can identify and remove all the characters, so also the currency symbols and the m's and b's all at once?

**To replicate the dataset:**

```
dataset <- structure(list(Event = structure(2:5, .Label = c("Event", "Labour Costs YoY", 
                                                    "Unemployment Change (000's)", "Unemployment Rate", "Jobseekers Net Change"), 
                                    .Names = c("", "", "", ""), class = "factor"), var1 = c("13.34m", "$16.91b", "-£1125.91m", "¥1012.74b"), var2 = c(0.026, -0.449, "0.89k", "9.56m")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all but a hyphen, digit or a dot, you can use

```r
dataset$var1 <- gsub("[^-0-9.]", "", dataset$var1)
```

The `[^-0-9.]` pattern is a negated character class that matches any char but the ones defined in the class.

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/qxoRND/1).

See [an online R demo](https://ideone.com/kxWLol):

```r
dataset <- structure(list(Event = structure(2:5, .Label = c("Event", "Labour Costs YoY", 
    "Unemployment Change (000's)", "Unemployment Rate", "Jobseekers Net Change"), 
   .Names = c("", "", "", ""), class = "factor"), var1 = c("13.34m", "$16.91b", "-£1125.91m", "¥1012.74b"), var2 = c(0.026, -0.449, "0.89k", "9.56m")), row.names = c(NA, 
   -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
gsub("[^-0-9.,]", "", dataset$var1)
##  => [1] "13.34"    "16.91"    "-1125.91" "1012.74"
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!

Do you also know if there is a way to store the removed values in a different colum variable? Just in case I need it for later, to identify if something was a million or a billion.